# load different content in the same li?

Tags: jquery, toggle

I wonder what the best way would be if I have li list with images and a headline and when I click on one off the images it will display some more text on top off the image(hiding the image) and when you click on the text it will display the image again.

If I have this to start with:

```
<ul>
<li>
<img src="image1.jpg"/><br>
Headline no1
<div> this is the text I want to show</div>
</li>
```

next li....

So what would be best?
Toggle the div  with jquery or some other suggestion?

Thanks for your input.

Comment: You're asking for an opinion. That's not what this site is about.

Comment: whatever works :) `div with jquery` should be fine..

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/accordion/ ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, this is what you're looking for:

```
<ul>
<li>
    <img class="switch" src="image1.jpg"/>
    <div class="hide switch" > this is the text        
I want to show</div>
    <h1>Headline no1</h1>
</li>
<li>
    <img class="switch" src="image1.jpg"/>    <div class="switch hide"> this is the text I want to show 2</div>
    <h2>Headline no2</h2>
</li>

</ul>
```

with this jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready( function(){

    $('.switch').click( function( ev ){
        var self = ev.currentTarget;
        var type = self.localName;
        var other;

        other = $(self).siblings( (type == 'div') ? 'img' : 'div' );

        $(self).addClass( 'hide' );
        other.removeClass( 'hide' );
    } );

} );
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Qv862/1/

Needs some styling of cause :)

Can be written more simple if you put your img in an div: http://jsfiddle.net/Qv862/2/

Comment: Thanks a lot Scheintod, both work great! If I want to fade between them how do I do that?

Comment: Good question. I wantet to look into css animations myself for quite some time. But with jQuery you could use this: http://jsfiddle.net/Qv862/3/

Comment: Great, just one last thing, if I click on the first one it changes to the text and then if I go to the second one, I would like to open the second text and close the first. That is close(go back to image) on everyone but the one I click on.

Comment: @Claes: This is a very different beast. Why not start a new question? You can use the last fiddle as starting point.

Answer (score 0):

For this my friend you need javascript (JS), use jquery, pure JS or whatever you want. But you need both object loaded in the DOM one visible and other not. And with JS change the display property in the style of the object.

Example in pure JS, with a div image and a div text:

```
<script>
  function showHide(idShow, idHide) {
     document.getElementById(idShow).style.display = "";
     document.getElementById(idhide).style.display = "none";
  }
</script>

<div id="image" onclick="showHide("text", "image");">
    <img>....</img>
</div>
<div id="text" style="display: none;" onclick="showHide("image", "text");">
    <p> some text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Luiso, but I need it to be unique ids since it´s going to be many images.